# Is it possible to see switching $n$ to $-n$ doesn't change the equation $(4^n-3^n)^2=12^{n-1}$ intuitively (without doing the calculations)?

Tags: calculus

Consider the equation $(4^n-3^n)^2=12^{n-1}$. In this equation when I switch $n$ to $-n$, I get the same equation,

$$\left(\frac1{4^n}-\frac1{3^n}\right)^2=\frac{\frac1{12}}{12^n}$$
$$\text{$(12^n)^2\times $Both  sides$$},\quad(3^n-4^n)^2=12^n\times12^{-1}$$
$$(4^n-3^n)^2=12^{n-1}$$
And we get the original equation. Hence if we define the function $f(n)=(4^n-3^n)^2-12^{n-1}$, we showed that it is an even function.

But unless many other even functions it was not obvious for me when I first look at this (without writing). I wonder Is it possible to intuitively see using $-n$ doesn't change the equation? I mean is there some mathematical facts behind that which cause this equation have such a property?

Comment: Seems like you've shown that $f(n)=0$ if and only if $f(-n)=0$.  That doesn't mean $f$ is even.

Comment: And, in particular, $f$ isn't even, which is kind of obvious when you consider large values of $n$.

Comment: That makes sense. My conclusion was incorrect.

Comment: This is a particular case of $((k+1)^n-k^n)^2=(k(k+1))^{n-1}$ with the solutions $n=\pm1$: when $n=+1$ you get $1$ on both sides and when $n=-1$ you get $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$ on both sides, but not an obvious symmetry.  (As with other questions involving powers, there may also be complex solutions)

Comment: FYI, the equation can be written as $\bigg(\dfrac 34\bigg)^n+\bigg(\dfrac 43\bigg)^n=\dfrac{25}{12}$.